# How to ignore _bookdown.yml to render a chapter using its own YAML header?

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown

I have multiple chapters in their own Rmd files and `_bookdown.yml` and `_output.yml` files which builds a book as expected. I am writing a thesis and some of these chapters include YAML headers which should render them independently as articles for particular journals. However I can't find a way to make bookdown honour these header blocks while the book's `_bookdown.yml` and `_output.yml` files are around. `gitbook::render_chapter()` does not do this.

So, how can we tell bookdown to ignore the `_bookdown.yml` and `_output.yml` files and instead render a chapter using its own YAML header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to create a `_bookdown_mychapter.yml` file particularly for each chapter that needs to be built as an article. In here include `rmd_files: ["mychapter.Rmd"]` to tell bookdown to include only the single chapter. Then use

```
bookdown::render_book("mychapter.Rmd", config_file = "_bookdown_mychapter.yml")
```

to specify that this YAML file should be used instead of the default `_bookdown.yml`.